# Unable to import anything in itorch notebook

Tags: python, numpy, ipython, jupyter-notebook, torch

I have installed IPython notebook,torch and Itorch on my Ubuntu 16.04.
I open an iTorch notebook using:

```
itorch notebook
```

In the notebook I am able to use:

```
require 'nn'
nn.Sequential() 
nn.SpatialConvolution(1, 6, 5, 5)
```

Basically I am able to use the functions of torch.
But when I import any python library as numpy or pandas:

```
import numpy as np
```

I get the following error:

```
[string "import numpy as np..."]:1: syntax error near 'numpy'
```

Even when i run itorch in terminal I get the same error.
Plz help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multilingual notebooks turned out to be very complicated to implement, so Jupyter notebooks can only use one language at a time. See e.g. [here](https://github.com/jupyterhub/jupyterhub/issues/202). Unless `iTorch` defines a [magic](https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/3/interactive/magics.html) or something for using Python too, there's no way to use both in the same notebook. Sorry.

Comment: Thanks I found out PyTorch which works well for both python and torch